# g++: Is there a way to access compile flags inside the code that is being compiled?

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there a way (e.g., defined constants) to access compile flags with which the compiler was run inside the code that is being compiled.

For example, I want a program that writes the flags with which it was compiled.

```
int main(){
    std::cout << COMPILE_FLAGS << std::endl;
}
```

Do such constants exist for gcc/g++? Or even better: Are there constants that are defined both in gcc and clang?

I am especially interested in examining the optimization level and the value of the `-march` flag. So, if there are no constants that show all flags, are there at least ones that display these values?

Comment: If nothing else, you should be able to hack something together using a makefile that simultaneously sets an optimization flag, and writes a constant to a header file.

Comment: I would try to look that up in the debug information that is stored with the code, IF it is compiled with such information. In general I would say there is no way, because we compile to machine code, and this would be entirely unnecessary information at run-time in most cases. I mean most flags influence which machine-instructions are chosen and which optimizations can be done, so you may be able to deduce some of the flags from the machine-code itself.

Answer (score 1):

The following command prints out all predefined macros:

```
g++ -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

This works with both gcc and g++. You can check yourself - unfortunately, there is no macro, that gives easy access to the full gcc/g++ command line.

Fortunately, most **-m...** flags result in adequate precompiler macros to be defined. For example, **-m64** defines **__x86_64** and **-m32** defines **__code_model_32__** . Or for **-march**: **-march=core-avx2** results in **#define __core_avx2__ 1** .

Just add the option, that you need to check, on the command line above, and check the result for new macro defines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the compile flags or the script that generates the compilation command, you could add a **-DCOMPILE_FLAGS**=<*the flags you are interested in*> to your build to actually create that constant.

From the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> -D name=definition The contents of definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a
>   ‘#define’ directive. In particular, the definition will be truncated
>   by embedded newline characters.